# shortcut macros not working in TeX4ht

Tags: macros, tex4ht

```
\documentclass{book}


\begin{document}
\newcommand{\testscsar}{E_c}

This is for test $Ec\testscsar$ 

\end{document}
```

Above code works everything fine to generate HTML conversion, but if I place the `\newcommand{\testscsar}{E_c}` before `\begin{document}`, example:

```
\newcommand{\testscsar}{E_c}
\begin{document}
```

then the subscript tags are not working properly in `HTML`. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `_` and `^` characters can be detected by `tex4ht` only after `\begin{document}`, so the earlier definitions don't have an effect. You can use `\sb` and `\sp` commands instead:

```
\documentclass{book}
\newcommand{\testscsar}{E\sb{c}}


\begin{document}

This is for test $Ec\testscsar$ 

\end{document}
```

To get tags for  subscripts, use the following configuration file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\begin{document}
\Configure{SUB}{\HCode{<sub>}\NoFonts}{\EndNoFonts\HCode{</sub>}}
\Css{sub .cmmi-7{font-size:0.8rem;}}
\EndPreamble
```

[image]

Comment: If I follow the said suggestion, still the subscript tag not comes in HTML, and the output is <p class="noindent" >This is for test <span 
class="cmmi-10">EcE</span><sub><span 
class="cmmi-7">c</span></sub>
</p>

Comment: @MadyYuvi please see the edit

Comment: thanks, its working fine, closing } was missing at the end of the line: \Css{sub .cmmi-7{font-size:0.8rem;}}, please correct it...

Comment: is there any similar other things (like super ans subscripts) in HTML conversion? If so, can you help me to send the list, so that I'll be aware of that, please...

Comment: @MadyYuvi subsripts and superscripts are unique because it involves category code changes, I think.